# 60's or 70's monster movie whose victims are caught and wrapped in a cape or coat

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

Just like the title says. I went to the movie with my sister when we were less than ten years old. It was a double matinee with The Green Slime playing as well. All I can remember is this person whose face was obscured and had a long dark coat or cape on. He would slowly come up behind the victims and wrap them in it. It was really creepy. Any help would be great.

Comment: It's a long shot, but on a review of The Green Slime I saw a comment from someone who remembered seeing it as a double feature with one of the Christopher Lee Fu Manchu films.  Any chance it was one of them?

Answer (score 3):

"The Wild, Wild Planet" (1966)?

This one involved people being kidnapped from Earth by women who are accompanied by mutants in black shades and long black coats. The mutants would come up behind people and wrap them in their coats and shrink them down to doll size and then cart them away in a suitcase. Here is a scene from TCM.com which shows a failed abduction attempt which leaves the victim looking like a dwarf. It starts at 1:45 of the video.

http://www.tcm.com/mediaroom/video/495701/Wild-Wild-Planet-The-Movie-Clip-Proteo-Theater.html

It's a bit of a stretch, but I can imagine this movie being on a double bill with "The Green Slime" (1968), because both movies were released close together and shared two of the same producers (Ivan Reiner, Walter Manley). Also, the writer of "The Green Slime" was Bill Finger, who wrote "Snow Devils", a sequel to "The Wild, Wild Planet". I can't find a picture of this particular drive-in double bill, though.

Comment: I think this just might be it. I will have to try and find the complete movie to see if the scene in my memory banks fits it. Thank you so much!

Comment: John T. The movie should be available at warnerarchive.com. I ordered mine from BestBuy online.